# How can I wrap this particular function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

```
  connection.query(selectMailgunChecked, function(err, rows){
    if (err) throw err;
    var emails = rows.map(function(a) {return a.email});
    var from = 'sample@email.com';
    emails.forEach(function sort(entry){
        mailgunSend(entry,from,contentHTML,contentRAW,subject,tags);
    });
  });
```

I am using this package (installed by https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) in my meteor app - https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/.

Code above doesn't working, when running app I get an error - "Can't wait without fiber". I guess that I have to wrapp function(err,rows) but how can I do it? Tutorials that I found in the web are not really fixing my problem.

Comment: Fibers is Meteor's way to deal with Event Loops. Have you tried numtel's package? https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/mysql

Comment: You need to use Meteor.wrapAsync

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sync = Meteor.wrapAsync(connection.query, connection);
var rows = sync(selectMailgunChecked);
var emails = rows.map(function(a) {
     return a.email
});
var from = 'sample@email.com';
emails.forEach(function(entry) {
    mailgunSend( entry, from, contentHTML, contentRAW, subject, tags);
});
```

This code handle error with TypeCast property.

Answer (score 1):

You probably only need to wrap the `connection.query` function.

```
var sync = Meteor.wrapAsync(connection.query);
var rows = sync(selectMailgunChecked);
var emails = rows.map(function(a) {
     return a.email
});
var from = 'sample@email.com';
emails.forEach(function(entry) {
    mailgunSend( entry, from, contentHTML, contentRAW, subject, tags);
});
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error: "Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined".

Comment: I don't think that error is related to the code above, given that the term `typeCast` doesn't appear anywhere in this. On which line is that error supposed to happen? Did you look at the stack?

Comment: http://iv.pl/images/29543567085031627934.png - here's the screen.
`var rows = sync(selectMailgunChecked);` is `136:14`, 
`159:3` is just a function call,
`selectMailgunChecked` variable is some SQL SELECT query.

Comment: well, then one of the variables you are passing to `mailgunSend` is probably undefined. Without knowing which one it is, there is no way of saying whether the error is in the code here or elsewhere. Only the first two arguments are defined in the code here.

Comment: I defined them in the code. There is the same error.

Comment: well again, you'll need to put in some `console.log`s to see which one is undefined.

Comment: It is not related to variables. Error happens even when I comment out `emails.forEach` and when I define variables right before it. It somehow related to the `sync(selectMailgunChecked)`.

Comment: and where is `selectMailgunChecked` defined? anyhow. I answered your question. Me helping you debug your code for undefined variables seems unproductive via comments on SO.

Comment: Also error points out Connection.js, line 192. There is what it contain - http://pastebin.com/g5uAB8hT